# How to format list column header in Sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-2016

I am working on Sharepoint 2016 and unfortunately in Sharepoint Designer 2013 there is no design view hence need to depend on code to format column header.

I have a list having 3 columns. I want to format them with below formatting:

alignment - center
background color - Blue
Text color - white
font family - calibri
size - medium
cell boardr color - white

I will add a script editor webpart, and need code to put there.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually run Designer 2010 and 2013 at the same time. Just make sure that they are both the same editions (32 or 64 bit). You also need to install 2013 first so that's perfect for you.

This tool: https://divtable.com/table-styler/ can help you learn how to use CSS to style your tables.

Comment: thanks for response. But i afraid that in sharepoint designer 2013 there is no deisgner mode hence it would be difficult. can u pls help me that how can i put css code into thesharepoint? should i use content editor or script editor?

Comment: That's what I'm telling you...you can install Designer 2010 as well - then you'll have a design mode. You can use the script editor or the content editor - both will work.